# If $f$ is $\beta$-smooth and non-negative, then $|f'(x)|^2\le 2\beta f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, optimization

I am reading a paper, and I found this conclusion from a proof.[image]

I am wondering why we can conclude that if a function $f$ is $\beta$-smooth and non-negative, then $|f'(x)|^2\le 2\beta f(x)$.

A simple definition of $\beta$-smooth is $|f''(x)| \le \beta$.

Comment: If additionally you assume that $f'(x)\ge 0$ everywhere and for some $x_0$, we have  $f(x_0)=0=f'(x_0)$, then
$f''(x)≤\beta$
implies
$$ f''(x)f'(x) ≤ \beta f'(x).$$
This LHS is $((f')^2)'/2$. Integrating from $x_0$ to $x$ gives
$$ f'(x)^2 \le 2\beta f(x).$$

Comment: can you share the paper where this is from?

Comment: Thank you Khor. Your answer provides a good point to me. The conclusion comes from the page 4 (top) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.02564.pdf.